# MutationObserver as property of object fails to observe immediately after being disconnected

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have the following class:

```
class CustomOption extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.addEventListener("mousedown", this.isSelecting);
        this.addEventListener("mouseup", this.setSelection);
        this.addEventListener("mouseenter", this.startHover);
        var customOption = this;
        this.observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
            customOption.customSelect.adjustSize();
            customOption.backgroundColor = customOption.style.backgroundColor;
            if (customOption.customSelected.hoveredOption == customOption) {
                customOption.setBackgroundColorUnobtrusively(customOption.selectedColor);
            }
        });
        this.observer.observe(this, { childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true, attributes: true, attributeFilter: ["style"] });
    }

    ...

    setBackgroundColorUnobtrusively(color) {
        this.observer.disconnect();
        this.style.backgroundColor = color;
        this.observer.observe(this, { characterData: true, subtree: true, attributes: true, attributeFilter: ["style"] });
    }
}
```

When I call `setBackgroundColorUnobtrusively` on a CustomOption object, the observer doesn't actually start observing again. If I go to the console in a browser and do it this way, however, it still works after calling `disconnect` and `observe` again:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("custom-option")[0];
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
    x.customSelect.adjustSize();
    x.backgroundColor = x.style.backgroundColor;
    if (x.customSelected.hoveredOption == x) {
        x.setBackgroundColorUnobtrusively(x.selectedColor);
    }
});
observer.disconnect();
x.style.backgroundColor = "white";
observer.observe(x, { characterData: true, subtree: true, attributes: true, attributeFilter: ["style"] });
```

Any clue why that may be? Does it have something to do with the reference to the MutationObserver? I have done checks and `this` in `setBackgroundColorUnobtrusively` seems to be bound properly. This feels strange to me...

Comment: The only difference is that it's using your custom element in `this` so I guess it somehow differs from the actual DOM element returned by standard DOM methods.

Comment: The weird thing is that I have compared `this` to the first CustomOption element (the one I use to test to see if its observer is working) in the DOM in `setBackgroundColorUnobtrusively` and it comes back to be true...

Comment: And if I create a new MutationObserver in `setBackgroundColorUnobtrusively` instead of reusing the old one, that ends up working as well.

Comment: Do you mean `this === document.getElementsByTagName("custom-option")[0]`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Can you make it happen in a live snippet (either [right inside the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) or on jsfiddle)?

Comment: While trying to reproduce the issue with a live snippet, I figured out the answer! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is pretty straightforward:

In the constructor, I include `childList: true` in the *options* argument when calling `observe`, however, when I start observing again in `setBackgroundColorUnobtrusively`, I fail to include that option.

The takeaway: Be careful when listing your options in observe and make sure you know what they do!

[More info on options for `observe`](https://javascript.info/mutation-observer)

Comment: You should make a separate method like startObserving and call it from the constructor and that other function.